# Body Mapping template AWS lambda API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I need to pass 2 arrays and 2 vars. with API to LAmbda function

I get everytime this:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\',\' (code 44)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, \'true\', \'false\' or \'null\')\n at [Source: [B@5a648099; line: 5, column: 11]"}
```

My template mapping:

```
{
    "items":
[
#foreach($elem in $input.params('items').split(','))
    {
        "ids": $elem.ids,

        "contents": $elem.contents
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
],
"QueryID": $input.params('QueryID'),
"nR": $input.params('nR')
}
```

Comment: can you show us what the original request looks like?

Comment: I'm thinking that one or more of the values needs to be double quote wrapped (JSON string) but can't be sure without knowing what the request looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting your values:

```
{
    "items": [
    #foreach($elem in $input.params('items').split(','))
        {
            "ids": "$elem.ids",
            "contents": "$elem.contents"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
    ],
    "QueryID": "$input.params('QueryID')",
    "nR": "$input.params('nR')"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are trying to pass items in the "params" field. If you are passing in `items`, `QueryID`, and `nR` every time, just put `$input.json('$')` (only that, remove everything else, even the surrounding `{}`). If that doesn't work, refer to [@dave-maple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620237/dave-maple)'s answer